# I would like to add ssl certificate to my already existing wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have site named as www.splessons.com and it has 500 articles and now i would like to add ssl certificate to it. My doubt is does this effect to my old articles.

Doubts:
1) Does it effects to my old articles ?
2) Some of images have in articles like http://www.splessons.com/images/splessons.jpg what will happen after i add ssl to my site. I mean after adding ssl, https://www.splessons.com/images/splessons.jpg will work fine or not ?
3) Do i need to take any precautions ?

Thanks,

Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add SSL to your website it simply adds the https:// version. It will not remove the http:// version unless you force SSL, in which all users will be redirected from http to https.

Whenever you change your permalink structure you want to be thinking about the best SEO practices and metrics. If you do decide to force SSL then you will want to make sure you do it with a proper 301 redirect.

Also, look into CloudFlare.com or another similar CDN (Cache Delivery Network). Depending on the reason you are looking to implement SSL this may be a good solution for you.